# Using Jade Array in Javascript transforms it to a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am passing an array of objects to my jade template, and want to use it as `var` in my js.

it seems to be transferred correctly, as

```
each level, i in stats
    .levelStats
```

creates 4 divs (as expected)

now i have

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var statData = "!{stats}"
```

which, as far as i know, should load the data into a javascript var.
it does that, in a way...

```
console.log(statData);
// output: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
// this means the correct data must be there..somewhere

console.log(typeof statData);
// output: string
```

what am I doing wrong?
how can i get the whole array into the var?

## solution + lesson:

`var foo = "!{bar}"` makes the data a string (pretty obvious in restrospective)

right way to go: `var foo = !{bar}`

Comment: can you provide a sample of stats ? maybe try to use `"!{level}"` instead of `"!{stats}"`

Comment: each entry in `stats` looks like 
{
            amountTaken     : 0,
            amountCorrect   : 0,
            totalTimeTaken  : 0,
            avgTimeTaken    : 0,
            daysAgo         : []
          }

for clarity: the jade code and javascript code are seperate. jade gets the array and loops over it to create divs.
then i want that same array in a `var` to use it inside a diagram

Comment: have you tried : `"!{JSON.stringify(stats)}"`

Comment: this throws `Uncaught ReferenceError: statData is not defined`

Comment: what about : `console.log(JSON.stringify(statData));`

Comment: `"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"`
:(

Comment: before that you told me : `Uncaught ReferenceError: -------> statData <------- is not defined`, but i was talking about `stats` : `JSON.stringify(stats)`

Comment: yes i had removed stringify from the assignment. i now have it at `var statData = "!{JSON.stringify(stats)}"` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(statData));`
output: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: statData is not defined`
the syntaxError is at local:1.... which holds THIS: http://pastebin.com/vtLqh3wG (on one line) ... the data is there

Comment: WAIT A SECOND. those quotes seem to break the objects? or is it just pastebin highlighting?

Comment: Yes, you right about the quotes ...

Comment: haha guess what... `var statData = !{JSON.stringify(stats)}` (without quotes) and it works :D thank you bro :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
each level, i in stats
    .levelStats
```

You are looping over (an array ?) `stats` where `i` is an index and `level` the element of your array at `stats[i]`.

but you don't seem to use the elements separatly :
`var statData = "!{stats}"`

stats still the array, you will find each element in `level` !

---

***Edit*** :
After clarification, to keep the whole array and set it to a variable :

```
var statData = !{JSON.stringify(stats)}
```

Comment: i WANT the whole array in the javascript variable.
the `each level, i in stats` is only for jade to create a div for every entry (=key)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a string in the `<script>` tag. How to make array into a string, so that you can convert it back later? JSON.stringify.

So, something like this should work:

```
script.
  var statData = !{JSON.stringify(stats)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent full day to make it work. It is more advanced example, but we pass array to js in jade/pug file. Here we pass array of locations to google maps init script. Use it like this: 
1)Prepare data on the server

```
JSON.stringify(locations = [
        { lat: -31.563910, lng: 147.154312 },
        { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
        { lat: 52.319277, lng: 21.000466 }
        ])
```

2)pass it to your pug/jade page. 
There, use this with variable that you pass, for example: DATA_THAT_YOUPASS

```
script.
                 function initMap() {
                 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 zoom: 3,
                 center: {lat: 52.5191758, lng: 23.0002262}
                 });
                 // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
                 var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                 // Add some markers to the map.
                 // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
                 // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
                 // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
                 var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
                 return new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: location,
                 label: labels[i % labels.length]
                 });
                 });
                 // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
                 var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
                 {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
                 }
                 var mydata = !{DATA_THAT_YOUPASS}
                 console.log(mydata);
                 console.log(mydata);
                 var locations = mydata;
             #map
            script(src='https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js')
            // Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key.
            script(async='', defer='', src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap')
```